# Producing multiple full copies of an array based on a criterion in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, indexing

I'm trying to figure out an array-indexing method to save the entire array for each value above a cutoff. The matrices I'm working with have ~10^9 elements, so writing a for loop is out of the question.

As an example, suppose there's a matrix

```
Vals=[96 92 97;83 90 95]
```

and since my cutoff is 95 this corresponds to a matrix

```
ExceedsCutoff=[1 0 1;0 0 1]
```

I would like to use ExceedsCutoff as a logical to produce a matrix WantedOutput with

```
WantedOutput(1,:,:)=Vals
WantedOutput(2,:,:)=zeros(2,3)
WantedOutput(3,:,:)=zeros(2,3)
WantedOutput(4,:,:)=zeros(2,3)
WantedOutput(5,:,:)=Vals
WantedOutput(6,:,:)=Vals
```

since the 1st, 5th, and 6th elements of ExceedsCutoff are 1. Any ideas on how to do this? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple multiplication with bsxfun() will do this for you:

```
Vals=[96 92 97;83 90 95];
Vals=permute(Vals,[3,1,2]);
Cutoff = 95;
ExceedsCutoff=Vals >= Cutoff;

WantedOutput = bsxfun(@times,ExceedsCutoff(:),Vals);
% Or, for MATLAB2016b and older
WantedOutput = ExceedsCutoff(:).*Vals;
```

Comment: Yes, this works great! The only thing I added was the line permute(WantedOutput,[2,3,1]) to get the dimensions of WantedOutput the same as those of the input arrays. I'm using R2014a but bsxfun seems to work fine anyway.